# Preventing GUI From Freezing When Calling SwingWorker.get( )

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a program where I am loading a file while at the same time I am displaying a window to inform the user that the file is being loaded. I decided to make a FileLoader class that was a SwingWorker which actually handled loading the file and a ProgressWindow that implements PropertyChangeListener to inform the user about the status of the SwingWorker that was passed into it.

My code currently looks like this:

```
FileLoader loader = new FileLoader(filePath);
new ProgressWindow(loader, "Loading File", "Loading File");
//ProgressWindow's constructor calls loader.execute() inherited from SwingWorker
doc = loader.get(); //GUI Freezes when called
```

The problem is that whenever I call loader.get(), it freezes the GUI, thus the progress bar in the Progress Window doesn't run and the whole thing is pointless. As far as I can tell, this is because the thread controlling the GUI is the same thread that calls loader.get(), which goes on hold while loader.execute() is running.

So far, I've tried creating a new thread for either the loader.get() command or the loader.execute() method, and calling SwingUtilities.invokeLater() on the thread, but then the whole program freezes.

I've considered creating a ChangeListener for when SwingWorker.isDone() and then running loader.get(), but this would require some reworking of my code that I would rather not do.

Could anyone tell me what the best way is to get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get()` is like `join()` in that it will block until called, and will wait for the SwingWorker to finish before being called. Using it wrongly can completely nullify all the advantages of using a SwingWorker in the first place.

Solution: Don't call `get()` until you know that the SwingWorker is done with its processing, by either calling it in the SwingWorker's `done()` method, or if you need to call it from the calling code, then in a PropertyChangeListener that has been added to the SwingWorker when the SwingWorker's "state" property is SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE.

Something like:

```
  final FileLoader loader = new FileLoader(filePath);

  loader.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("state".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
           // since DONE is enum, no need for equals(...) method
           if (evt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
              try {
                 loader.get();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
           }
        }
     }
  });

  new ProgressWindow(loader, "Loading File", "Loading File");
```

Note: code not compiled nor tested

Edit: try/catch added.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't call get() during done() because I need to actually return the results of get() to the calling method and done() doesn't return anything. And the PropertyChangeListener was exactly the sort of thing I was hoping to avoid, but I suppose it may be necessary.

Comment: Why avoid it? It's a piece of cake to code, and is necessary if you need to call get().

Comment: It just required code rewriting in another part of the program, but I think that's going to have to be necessary.

Comment: It also meant that I had to write more code in more places. I was hoping for a nice, encapsulated solution.

Comment: @Thunderforge did you read SwingWorker API ??? publish() or process(), btw API describe right solution and including code

Comment: I did read those, but it looked like they were for updating things like JLabels in the middle of the task, which wasn't what I wanted to do since I needed something returned at the end of the task.

Comment: @Thunderforge: in general calling `get()` is a *good thing*, since this will allow you to capture exceptions that might have occurred during your SwingWorker's run. And in fact my code above is in error since I do not have a try/catch block which likely will be needed.

Comment: @Thunderforge here are lots of code for SwingWorker and with FileReaders or WebDownLoaders with output to the very sensitive JProgressBar, really my view is that another issue could be hidden in the rest of your code, for better help sooner post an SSCCE

Comment: By the way, I did get it to work your way, so I think I'll be selecting yours as the best answer. It's not the way that I was hoping for since it's not a fully encapsulated solution, but it's one that works and works well. Thanks!

Comment: @Thunderforge: there are likely ways to refactor so that the solution is cleaner. I can't help you with this right now given our limited knowledge of your problem, but I know that one way or another, it can be done. Much luck!

Answer (score 3):

> So far, I've tried creating a new thread for either the loader.get() command or the loader.execute() method, and calling SwingUtilities.invokeLater() on the thread, but then the whole program freezes.

If you call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` on the thread that will execute the thread in the EDT which freezes the GUI.  Instead, run the thread by calling it's `start()` method and only use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` when you need to update the progress bar in the `PropertyChangeListener`.

Comment: I've tried to play around with this, but since a thread can't return a value, I'm not finding a good way to implement it.

Comment: You can modify a value outside of the Thread instead.  Or if you really need a return value use a [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) thread.

Comment: I like the idea of FutureTask, but I'm having a hard time getting my head wrapped around it. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I have create a WorkerThread class which take care of Threads and GUI current/main thread .
i have put my GUI application in construct() method of WorkerThread when an event fire to start XXXServer then all threads are activate and GUI work smoothlly wihout freeze. have a look.

```
/**
* Action Event
* 
* @see java.awt.event.ActionListener#actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)
*/
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    log.info("actionPerformed begin..." + ae.getActionCommand());

    try {
        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(btnStart.getText())) {
             final int portNumber = 9990;
             try {

                 WorkerThread workerThread = new WorkerThread(){
                    public Object construct(){

                        log.info("Initializing the Server GUI...");
                        // initializing the Server
                         try {
                            xxxServer = new XXXServer(portNumber);
                            xxxServer.start();
                            btnStart.setEnabled(false);                             
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            log.info("actionPerformed() Start button ERROR IOEXCEPTION..." + e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };workerThread.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.info("actionPerformed() Start button ERROR..." + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
             }


        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(btnStop.getText())) {
            log.info("Exit..." + btnStop.getText());
            closeWindow();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log
            .info("Error in ServerGUI actionPerformed==="
                + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```