# gui frozen when calling SwingWorker method get()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, progress-bar, swingworker

```
class ProgressBarSwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>
    {
        private int byteWritten = 0;
        private String downloadDir = "";
        private String fileAddress = "";
        private String fileName = "";
        private int fileSize;

        public void fileUrlReadAndDownload(String fileAddress, String downloadDir)
        {
            OutputStream outStream = null;
            URLConnection uCon = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            try
            {
                message.setText(fileName + "in Update");
                URL Url;
                byte[] buf;
                int byteRead;
                Url = new URL(fileAddress);
                outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadDir));
                uCon = Url.openConnection();
                is = uCon.getInputStream();
                buf = new byte[size];
                while ((byteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1)
                {
                    outStream.write(buf, 0, byteRead);
                    byteWritten += byteRead;
                    pbar.setValue(byteWritten);
                    frame.repaint();
                }

                message.setText("update finish");
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                message.setText("server is not runing.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally
            {
                try
                {
                    is.close();
                    outStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public ProgressBarSwingWorker(String fileAddress, String downloadDir, String fileName, int fileSize)
        {
            this.fileAddress = fileAddress;
            this.downloadDir = downloadDir;
            this.fileName = fileName;
            this.fileSize = fileSize;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
        {
            pbar.setMaximum(fileSize);
            fileUrlReadAndDownload(fileAddress, downloadDir);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done()
        {
            try
            {
                get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

i make swingworker like this for downloading file from http and show progress bar GUI

i made 10 progreebarswingworker instance and put in list and run like this

```
for(ProgressBarSwingWorker p : progressList)
{
p.execute();
}
```

and all progressList is start same time

i want execute step by step wait other progress is finish

so i put done() or get() method like this

```
for(ProgressBarSwingWorker p : progressList)
    {
    p.execute();
p.done(); // or p.get();
    }
```

this code execute progress other progress is done

but! GUI is freeze so i can't show any JLabel change or JProgressBar

how to to wait other progress finish without gui freeze?

Comment: Have a look here:
[Preventing GUI from freezing when calling SwingWorker.get()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547537/preventing-gui-from-freezing-when-calling-swingworker-get)

Comment: @GeeHad i use code in your link but it doesn't work too i attach my code in thread i'm wrong?

Comment: “how to to wait other progress finish without gui freeze?” That’s simply the wrong question. Waiting in the GUI thread implies freezing of the GUI. *Don’t wait inside the GUI thread*.

Comment: @Holger hmm... and how to know GUI SwingWorker thread is done? i want download file one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying something conceptionally wrong. You try to wait for a completion to perform another action which yields to the single-threaded behavior that you want to avoid. It doesn’t matter how you rewrite your code, as long as you always end up trying to *wait* your GUI will *freeze*.

You have to change your concept. Instead of waiting you have to tell Swing what to do when the task has finished, i.e. start the next one. You don’t need to invoke `get` as it has nothing to do with defining the next action. You can either:

- Tell your `ProgressBarSwingWorker` the reference to the next one and invoke its `execute` method inside the `done` method

  ```
  class ProgressBarSwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Object, Object>
  {
    ProgressBarSwingWorker next;
    // …
    public ProgressBarSwingWorker(ProgressBarSwingWorker nextWorker)
    {
      next=nextWorker;
    }
    // …
    @Override
    protected void done()
    {
      if(next!=null) next.execute();
    }
  }
  ```

  or
- add a listener which will invoke the `execute` method of the next `ProgressBarSwingWorker`

  ```
  ProgressBarSwingWorker previous=null;
  for(final ProgressBarSwingWorker p: progressList)
  {
    if(previous==null) p.execute();
    else previous.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener()
    {
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
      {
        if("state".equals(evt.getPropertyName())
        && evt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE)
          p.execute();
      }
    });
    previous=p;
  }
  ```

Comment: it work fine!! thanks i looking for find answer all day long :( thanks a lot !!!